# React native detect loading image

Tags: react-native, react-native-listview

I have a problem. I use onLoad, onLoadStart and onLoadEnd in Image. I want to wait while server get response link image and show image, add loading. But its jerking constantly.

```
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {loading: true}}

    return(
     <Image
        onLoad={(e) => this.setState({loading: true})}
        onError={(e) => this.setState({loading: false})}
        onLoadStart={(e) => this.setState({loading: false})}

        source={this.state.loading ? require('../../img/loading.gif') : { 
         uri: getBestUrl(artwork)}}
        style={styles.artworkImage}
        resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.cover}
      />)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you returning an image from your constructor or you didn't post all the code?

Now to the question, I think it won't work that way since it seems that will always change the state while it's loading your 'loading.gif' or your uri image. Also are you setting a height and weight to your image? This is needed as you can see in the docs

> Unlike with static resources, you will need to manually specify the
>   dimensions of your image.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#network-images

Maybe you can store the image path in your state and make a conditional rendering according to the state value. For example:

```
...
this.state = {
imagePath: null,
}
...

this.setState({
imagePath: getBestUrl(artwork);
});
...

{
this.state.imagePath ? <Image uri={require(this.state.imagePath)} /> : <Image uri={require('loading.gif')}
}
```

Consider the code above just as an example to express the idea.

Hope this can be worth for you.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I just added my code. You can look over. I have not done as an example